# How can I play a RealMedia stream?

Tags: video, streaming

I would like to play the RealMedia streams at http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/index.php/Main/AdditiveCombinatoricsMinicourse .

I have installed the RealPlayer beta but all that happens is that the browser saves a .ra file and then RealPlayer says it can't play it.

Interestingly, they work fine in mplayer on linux using `mplayer -playlist http://acstream.princeton.edu:8080/ramgen/blackboard/cs/additive_combinatorics/1_luca_trevisan_350k.rm` for example.  The stream itself is `rtsp://128.112.131.181:554/blackboard/cs/additive_combinatorics/1_luca_trevisan_350k.rm` and I thought Android had rtsp support.

Is there any way to play the videos in Android?

Edit: The answer shows how to play the rtsp streams. However, I would really like to be able to play the videos directly from their web page without having to extract each rtsp link manually using a separate computer.

Answer (score 5):

That's weird. I could stream this perfectly on my Android 2.3 stock browser.

For you, I'd suggest you do the following :-

1. Download [MX Video Player FREE](http://www.appbrain.com/app/mx-player/com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) (and a suitable codec for your phone)
2. Enter the URL `rtsp://128.112.131.181:554/blackboard/cs/additive_combinatorics/1_luca_trevisan_350k.rm` in your **stock browser**.
3. You'll see something like :

[image: This is what you should see] The above URL for lazy beans: [image: QR code]

Click on the MX Video Player and your video should load properly. duh! :D

Comment: Thanks! MX player does indeed seem to be the secret. I don't see how you played it directly from the http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/index.php/Main/AdditiveCombinatoricsMinicourse web page however. The stock browser offers you MX player as an option which gives me "Sorry, this video cannot be player" unless I feed it the rtsp link.  I am also on stock 2.3.

Comment: @RaphaelClifford Oh I didn't play from the page either. It wouldn't work anyway because the webpage has http:// protocols served instead of the rtsp URLs.

Comment: Oh OK. That seems to mean you need a separate PC to extract the rtsp link in order to play those videos on android doesn't it?

Comment: @RaphaelClifford Yes, the proper rtsp stream link needs to be found. Its a shame the website there did not configure MIME types properly for rtsp streaming. Maybe they want us to download the content instead of streaming.

Comment: Is it possible to download the contents instead of streaming it?

Comment: Basically I am just looking for an app/method that does the equivalent of mplayer -playlist http://acstream.princeton.edu:8080/ramgen/blackboard/cs/additive_combinatorics/1_luca_trevisan_350k.rm

Comment: @RaphaelClifford well here it seems the .rm files are simply plaintext files that contain the RTSP stream URL inside it. (meaning its a playlist file instead of the stream). You could perhaps set up a shell script that downloads these files and extract its contents or simply open these files individually using text editors on android and get the real link. I am not aware of apps that would do this currently.